# Post App Service Migration - Create Table Error

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

Having recently migrated my Azure Mobile Service to the Azure App Service platform I've noticed that I am now unable to create new tables?

I have created the tables through the SQL Server Management Studio, the same as I was doing previously with my Mobile Service, and then just adding the table as a 'New Table' within the Mobile Service. This used to pull the table I had created in that schema into the Mobile Service and make it accessible.

However, since going to App Services I have tried to do the same thing but get the following error:

> Table creation error! There was an error while creating table 'Items'.
>   '{   "Message": "An error has occurred.",   "ExceptionMessage": "The
>   specified schema name \"**SCHEMANAME**\" either does not exist or you
>   do not have permission to use it.",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",   "StackTrace": "   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at ......

To fix this I've tried changing the `MobileAppsManagement_EXTENSION_VERSION` to 'beta' from 'latest' which is apparently the MS Fix: 
https://www.gittprogram.com/question/32407_unable-to-create-new-table-since-migrated-azure-mobile-services-to-app-service.html

I Tried this but had no joy. Also checked to see if a new instance had been created in the move but I couldn't find anything suspicious...Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this particular error. What schema name are you using when you create the tables? You need to use the name of the mobile service as the schema name, not dbo. Also, be aware that creating tables in SQL Server management studio does not create required triggers and you need to create the __createdAt and __updatedAt columns. You're better off creating tables using the portal.

Comment: Hi Dale, your suggestion with the EXTENSION VERSION worked perfectly! I've created 80% of my tables through SQL Server Management Studio with no problems but didn't realise I was missing triggers! I'll head back to the portal from now on and compare the differences later. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently an issue with creating tables on migrated sites. We are working to resolve this and should have a fix ready in the next day or two. As a workaround, set the MobileAppsManagement_EXTENSION_VERSION app setting to 1.0.322 and you should be able to continue working.

Comment: Hiya, Just set that and works perfectly, great fix! Thanks very much!